# Setting a clip on a seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am having trouble clipping a `seaborn` plot (a `kdeplot`, specifically) as I thought would be fairly simple per [this example in the `matplotlib` docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/api/clippath_demo.html).

For example, the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])

random_points = np.array([p for p in np.random.random(size=(100, 2)) if 0 < p[0] < 1 and 0 < p[1] < 1])

kde = sns.kdeplot(random_points[:,0], random_points[:,1], ax=ax)

xmin, xmax = kde.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = kde.get_ylim()

patch = mpl.patches.Circle(((xmin + xmax)/2, (ymin + ymax) / 2), radius=0.4)
ax.add_patch(patch)
kde.set_clip_path(patch)
```

Results in the following output:

[image]

I would like to clip this result so that the KDE contour lines do not appear outside of the circle. I haven't found a way to do it thus far...is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serenity's answer works for simple shapes, but breaks down for reasons unknown when the shape contains more than three or so vertices (I had difficulty establishing the exact parameters, even). For sufficiently large shapes the fill flows into where the edge should be, [as for example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8ZvW.png).

It did get me thinking along the right path, however. While it doesn't seem to be possible to do so simply using `matplotlib` natives (perhaps there's an error in the code he provided anyway?), it's easy as pie when using the [`shapely`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) library, which is meant for tasks like this one.

**Generating the Shape**

In this case you will need shapely's [`symmetric_difference`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.symmetric_difference) method. A [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) is the set theoretic name for this cut-out operation.

For this example I've loaded a Manhattan-shaped polygon as a `shapely.geometry.Polygon` object. I won't covert the initialization process here, it's easy to do, and everything you expect it to be.

We can draw a box around our `manhattan` using `manhattan.envelope`, and then apply the difference. This is the following:

```
unmanhattan = manhattan.envelope.symmetric_difference(manhattan)
```

Doing which gets us to:

[image]

**Adding it to the Plot**

Ok, but this is a `shapely` object not a `matplotlib` `Patch`, how do we add it to the plot? The `descartes` library handles this conversion.

```
unmanhattan_patch = descartes.PolygonPatch(unmanhattan)
```

This is all we need! Now we do:

```
unmanhattan_patch = descartes.PolygonPatch(unmanhattan)
ax.add_patch(unmanhattan_patch)
sns.kdeplot(x=points['x_coord'], y=points['y_coord'], ax=ax)
```

And get:

[image]

And with a little bit more work extending this to the rest of the polygons in the view (New York City), we can get the following final result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess your example work only for 'imshow'.

To hide contours lines over the circle you have to plot 'inverse' polygon of desired color.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# Color plot except polygon
def mask_outside(poly_verts, facecolor = None, ax = None):
    from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
    from matplotlib.path import Path

    if ax is None: ax = plt.gca()
    if facecolor is None: facecolor = plt.gcf().get_facecolor()

    # Construct inverse polygon
    xlim, ylim = ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()
    bound_verts = [(xlim[0], ylim[0]), (xlim[0], ylim[1]), 
                   (xlim[1], ylim[1]), (xlim[1], ylim[0]), (xlim[0], ylim[0])]
    bound_codes = [Path.MOVETO] + (len(bound_verts) - 1) * [Path.LINETO]
    poly_codes = [Path.MOVETO] + (len(poly_verts) - 1) * [Path.LINETO]

    # Plot it
    path = Path(bound_verts + poly_verts, bound_codes + poly_codes)
    ax.add_patch(PathPatch(path, facecolor = facecolor, edgecolor = 'None', zorder = 1e+3))

# Your example
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])
random_points = np.array([p for p in np.random.random(size=(100, 2)) if 0 < p[0] < 1 and 0 < p[1] < 1])
kde = sns.kdeplot(random_points[:,0], random_points[:,1], ax=ax)

xmin, xmax = kde.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = kde.get_ylim()

patch = mpl.patches.Circle(((xmin + xmax) / 2, (ymin + ymax) / 2), radius=0.4)
mask_outside([tuple(x) for x in patch.get_verts()]) # call before add_patch!
ax.add_patch(patch)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This goes beyond clever and touches upon witchcraft! Note that a very small change (in this case, adding `sns.reset_orig()`, which I need) breaks this code and returns us to our original result; this is because `facecolor` is `(1,1,1,0)` at runtime in the original style (fully transparent) and `(1,1,1,1)` in the `seaborn` style. Manually fixating the latter fixes the issue.

Comment: Can this solution be extended to work with more complex shapes? The code as-is fails in the case of polygons with more than three or so sides. The following image demonstrates what happens: in this case `facecolor='yellow'` whilst `edgecolor='steelblue'`, but as you can see the anti-shape appears to swallow itself (?) somehow: http://i.imgur.com/gS5v8dk.png.